# Android - basic gesture detection in TableLayout

Tags: android, listener, gesture-recognition

I am new to android development, so please excuse the naivety of the post. I have a table layout in which i am dynamically adding text view to each cell. I wish to add a swipe detection on the cells and perform an action on the basis of which cell was swiped. I tried adding a onSwipeTouchListener on each of the cell.

```
TextView txtviewCell = new TextView(getActivity());
TableRow.LayoutParams paramsExample = new TableRow.LayoutParams(60, 60);
txtviewCell.setBackgroundColor(0xfffaf8ef);
txtviewCell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
paramsExample.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
txtviewCell.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);
final int currRow = i;
final int currCol = j;
txtviewCell.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(
        getActivity()) {
    public void onSwipeTop() {
        handleSwipe(currRow, currCol);
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
        handleSwipe(currRow, currCol);
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        handleSwipe(currRow, currCol);
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        handleSwipe(currRow, currCol);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
allCells[i][j] = txtviewCell;
```

Now when i swipe i get the control in onSwipe function, but i do not get the correct row number and col number. Is there a specific way to attach a swipe event on a textview and get the row number and col number of that cell?

Answer (score 0):

I guess every textview has different ID, so try getting the id and making a control flow with it.

Comment: Since i am dynamically generating the textviews, i couldn't find a way to assign a different ID to the textviews.

Comment: @user1045047 and they all have the same text to display?

Comment: No, different boxes have different text.

Comment: @user1045047 So what if you get the text from each widget and make a switch case to determine to which gesture corresponds?